# Why is Kibana trends not working?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin

I have created an data river from Twitter and loaded that data into Kibana dashboard using elasticsearch. While all the analytics tools mentioned there are working properly with my data,the "Trends" tool is showing an error " Oops! A time filter must exist for this panel to function". And I have tried applying filters too. But still the problem exist. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced this exact issue. The problem was that kibana assumes the timestamp to be @timestamp field , you need to override this to created_at timefield.
This can be done by going to the global settings in kibana and change @timestamp to created_at field.
After this , you can first change the dashboard settings to "Last 30 minutes" or so and use the trends panel.